# Dynamic list in GridView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

We are developing a Xamarin iOS shopping cart application in c# and visual studio 2017, We are using rest web services, We are successfully able to display item in the listview but now we want to display items in the grid format - multiple columns (2) and multiple rows. so that we can provide an option to swap between list and gridview. Data consists of Image and price, unitprice,Name,Pack. Can anyone suggest a way todo it or provide a sample code

Comment: refer to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-dynamic-gridview/

Comment: We have followed the document as your advice and we are able to display item dynamically in the griview, i appreciate the help